# gulp-single-file-component package does not create correct template output. Which gulp package will actually compile my .vue components correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, gulp

I am new to Vue.js, so please excuse my lack of knowledge. I am trying to use gulp to compile my vue files into correctly compiled files, but have been unsuccessful with vue files that have multiple 'template' tags. Any help is much appreciated.

my search-form.vue. mostly pulled from buefy site for table template.

```html
<template>
    <section>
        <b-field grouped group-multiline>
            <div class="control">
                <b-switch v-model="showDetailIcon">Show detail icon</b-switch>
            </div>
        </b-field>
        <b-table :data="data" ref="table" paginated per-page="5" :opened-detailed="defaultOpenedDetails" detailed detail-key="id" @details-open="(row, index) => $toast.open(`Expanded ${row.logID}`)" :show-detail-icon="showDetailIcon" aria-next-label="Next page" aria-previous-label="Previous page" aria-page-label="Page" aria-current-label="Current page">
            <template slot-scope="props">
                <b-table-column field="callerName" label="Caller" width="40" numeric>{{ props.row.callerName }}</b-table-column>
                <b-table-column field="logQuestion" label="Question" sortable>
                    <template v-if="showDetailIcon">
                        {{ props.row.logQuestion }}

                    </template>
                    <template v-else>
                        <a @click="toggle(props.row)">{{ props.row.logQuestion }}</a>
                    </template>
                </b-table-column>
                <b-table-column field="logAnswer" label="Answer" sortable>{{ props.row.logAnswer }}</b-table-column>
                <b-table-column field="logDate" label="Log Date" sortable centered><span class="tag is-success">{{ new Date(props.row.logDate).toLocaleDateString() }}</span></b-table-column>
            </template>
            <template slot="detail" slot-scope="props">
                <article class="media">
                    <figure class="media-left">
                        <p class="image is-64x64"><img src="/static/img/placeholder-128x128.png">/p>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="media-content">
                        <div class="content">
                            <p>
                                <strong>{{ props.row.customCategoryName }} {{ props.row.categories }}</strong>
                                <small>@{{ props.row.logStaffName }}</small>
                                <small>31m</small>
                                <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Proin ornare magna eros, eu pellentesque tortor vestibulum ut. Maecenas non massa sem. Etiam finibus odio quis feugiat facilisis.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </template>
        </b-table>
    </section>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
        name: 'search-form',
        data() {
            return {
                data: [],
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: 'logID',
                        label: 'Log ID',
                        visible: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'callerName',
                        label: 'Caller',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'logQuestion',
                        label: 'Question',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'logAnswer',
                        label: 'Answer',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'customCategoryName',
                        label: 'Custom Category',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'categories',
                        label: 'Categories',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'logStaffName',
                        label: 'Staff Name',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'logDate',
                        label: 'Log Date',
                        sortable: true
                    }
                ],
                isPaginated: true,
                isPaginationSimple: false,
                defaultSortDirection: 'asc',
                currentPage: 1,
                perPage: 15,
                isStriped: true,
                isHoverable: true,
                hasMobileCards: true,
                isEmpty: false,
                defaultOpenedDetails: [1],
                showDetailIcon: true
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            let self = this;
            axios.get('https://localhost:44390/Log')
                .then(response => {
                    self.data = response.data;
                    if (self.data.length === 0) {
                        self.isEmpty = true;
                    }
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },
        methods: {
            toggle(row) {
                this.$refs.table.toggleDetails(row)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

my gulpfile.js

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");
const vueify = require('gulp-vue-single-file-component');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('js:dev', gulp.series(compileVue, function () {
    return gulp.src('typescript/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler(err) {
                notify.onError({
                    title: `Gulp error in ${err.plugin}`,
                    message: err.toString()
                })(err);
            }
        }))
        .pipe(tsProject()).js
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/js/app"));
}));

function compileVue() {
    return gulp.src('typescript/**/*.vue')
        .pipe(vueify({ debug: true, loadCssMethod: 'loadCss' }))
        .pipe(babel({ plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-amd'] }))
        .pipe(rename({ ext: '.js', suffix: '.vue' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/js/app'));
}
```

My output from gulpfile function compileVue.

```js
define(["exports"], function (_exports) {
  "use strict";

  Object.defineProperty(_exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
  });
  _exports.default = void 0;
  var _default = {
    template: '<section><b-field grouped="" group-multiline=""><div class="control"><b-switch v-model="showDetailIcon">Show detail icon</b-switch></div></b-field><b-table :data="data" ref="table" paginated="" per-page="5" :opened-detailed="defaultOpenedDetails" detailed="" detail-key="id" @details-open="(row, index) => $toast.open(`Expanded ${row.logID}`)" :show-detail-icon="showDetailIcon" aria-next-label="Next page" aria-previous-label="Previous page" aria-page-label="Page" aria-current-label="Current page"><template slot-scope="props"><b-table-column field="callerName" label="Caller" width="40" numeric="">{{ props.row.callerName }}</b-table-column><b-table-column field="logQuestion" label="Question" sortable=""><template v-if="showDetailIcon">{{ props.row.logQuestion }}<template v-else=""><a @click="toggle(props.row)">{{ props.row.logQuestion }}</a></template></b-table-column><b-table-column field="logAnswer" label="Answer" sortable="">{{ props.row.logAnswer }}</b-table-column><b-table-column field="logDate" label="Log Date" sortable="" centered=""><span class="tag is-success">{{ new Date(props.row.logDate).toLocaleDateString() }}</span></b-table-column></template><template slot="detail" slot-scope="props"><article class="media"><figure class="media-left"><p class="image is-64x64"><img src="/static/img/placeholder-128x128.png">/p&gt;</p></figure><div class="media-content"><div class="content"><p><strong>{{ props.row.customCategoryName }} {{ props.row.categories }}</strong><small>@{{ props.row.logStaffName }}</small><small>31m</small><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Proin ornare magna eros, eu pellentesque tortor vestibulum ut. Maecenas non massa sem. Etiam finibus odio quis feugiat facilisis.</p></div></div></article></template></b-table></section></template>',
    name: 'search-form',

    data() {
      return {
        data: [],
        columns: [{
          field: 'logID',
          label: 'Log ID',
          visible: false
        }, {
          field: 'callerName',
          label: 'Caller',
          sortable: true
        }, {
          field: 'logQuestion',
          label: 'Question',
          sortable: true
        }, {
          field: 'logAnswer',
          label: 'Answer',
          sortable: true
        }, {
          field: 'customCategoryName',
          label: 'Custom Category',
          sortable: true
        }, {
          field: 'categories',
          label: 'Categories',
          sortable: true
        }, {
          field: 'logStaffName',
          label: 'Staff Name',
          sortable: true
        }, {
          field: 'logDate',
          label: 'Log Date',
          sortable: true
        }],
        isPaginated: true,
        isPaginationSimple: false,
        defaultSortDirection: 'asc',
        currentPage: 1,
        perPage: 15,
        isStriped: true,
        isHoverable: true,
        hasMobileCards: true,
        isEmpty: false,
        defaultOpenedDetails: [1],
        showDetailIcon: true
      };
    },

    mounted() {
      let self = this;
      axios.get('https://localhost:44390/Log').then(response => {
        self.data = response.data;

        if (self.data.length === 0) {
          self.isEmpty = true;
        }
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    },

    methods: {
      toggle(row) {
        this.$refs.table.toggleDetails(row);
      }

    }
  };
  _exports.default = _default;
});
```

I do not understand why the template property inside my generated output becomes corrupted. What am I doing incorrectly? I tried to include only the files responsible to not make my post convoluted.

I have been searching online for the last two days, but have not found any hard resolution to my problem, so here I am asking on SO.

Comment: I'm sure you could find more info online about using it with `Typescript` but you could try this `Gulp` plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-vueify2

Comment: .. Edit: it's important to note, using `Webpack` is the "recommended" way of doing this.. [see more here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-a-vue-js-app-using-single-file-components-without-the-cli-7e73e5b8244f)

Comment: Thank you for the links. I have tried your plugin in place of 'gulp-vue-single-file-component' and my vue files then become completely corrupted and are not loadable by requireJS. right NOW webpack may be the "recommended" way of doing this but I am more familiar with using Visual Studio and would like to keep the MVC structure.